# Why does my tensorflow code run so slow? Batch size is 1

Tags: python, tensorflow

So I have the following objective function. It only works for one training example at a time (I have my reasons for avoiding batches). As you can see it's very lightweight so I expect it to run blazingly fast.

```
def objective(data, lam, item_biases, latent_items, latent_users):  

    user = data[0]
    rated_item = data[1]
    unrated_item = data[2]


    rated_item_bias = item_biases[rated_item]
    unrated_item_bias = item_biases[unrated_item]

    rated_latent_item = latent_items[rated_item]
    unrated_latent_item = latent_items[unrated_item]

    latent_user = latent_users[user]

    rated_pred = rated_item_bias + tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(rated_latent_item, latent_user))
    unrated_pred = unrated_item_bias + tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(unrated_latent_item, latent_user))

    difference = rated_pred - unrated_pred
    obj = tf.sigmoid(difference)

    obj += lam * tf.reduce_sum(rated_item_bias**2)
    obj += lam * tf.reduce_sum(unrated_item_bias**2) 
    obj += lam * tf.reduce_sum(rated_latent_item**2) 
    obj += lam * tf.reduce_sum(unrated_latent_item**2)
    obj += lam * tf.reduce_sum(latent_user**2)
    return obj
```

However, when I train it as such:

```
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
for iteration in range(5):
    samples = sample_triple(data, valid, 100000)
    for sample in tqdm(samples):
        cvalues = sess.run([trainer, obj], feed_dict={input_data:sample})
```

it runs abysmally slowly. I have a vanilla Python SGD implementation (e.g. hand-derived gradients) and it runs at 80K iterations/ second. This tensorflow implementation runs at about 30 iterations/ second. This is clearly unreasonable. Obviously having a batch size of 1 will slow things down. But to 30 iterations/ second?

Is it the overhead of the `sess.run()` call? Is there a better way of making sure that I only take one sample at a time (it *has* to be SGD, no mini-batches)?

EDIT: I should add that it's reasonably fast if I don't feed it one item per batch (the objective function had to change) but that's suboptimal as I noted...

Comment: You can add the loop over mini-batches * in* the graph. As the update step is simply an operation, you can even add this directly to the graph. Doing so, you can change the "for sample in .." to load entire chunks and the loop inside the graph iterates over the chunk. The overhead of sess.run with feed_dict is large. This solution might hide the latency.

Comment: Where in the graph would that be done? In the optimizer maybe? It doesn't make sense to do it in my custom `objective` function so would I need to write my own optimizer to incorporate it into the graph?

Answer (score 1):

Could not fit the response in a comment. `session.run` does have some overhead. The overhead is most pronounced when you run trivial computation on GPU and feed large values. Feeding always takes values from CPU memory and copies them to GPU (if your computation is running on GPU). The base over is not that high though. For example this code take a second on my machine:

```
with tf.device('cpu'):
  a = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=())
  b = a  + 1

  with tf.Session() as sess:
    s = time.time()
    c = 0
    for x in xrange(8000):
      c += sess.run(b, feed_dict={a: x})
    print "Computed in ", c, "in", time.time() - s
```

To debug this further, I would suggest:

- Make sure that all the time is actually spent in `sess.run()`
- Make sure you are not feeding in very large amounts of data. It seems like `item_biases, latent_items, latent_users` are arrays but you are using a single element from them. Try feeding exactly what you need.
- Try running on CPU
- Try looking at performance timelines: https://towardsdatascience.com/howto-profile-tensorflow-1a49fb18073d
- If these steps don't reveal any simple fixes, do the loop over mini-batches in the graph using `tf.while_loop`.

Answer (score 0):

As iga points out, the overhead is due to the fact that the `sess.run()` call is copying memory back from the GPU to the CPU. This is an expensive operation. 
For that reason, it is best to design your training operations to have no return value, and then only query for the value of the cost function or the optimization variable irregularly. For example,

```
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
for iteration in range(5):
    samples = sample_triple(data, valid, 100000)
    for sample in tqdm(samples):
        sess.run( trainer, feed_dict={input_data:sample})
    cvalues = sess.run( obj, feed_dict={input_data:sample})
```

This way the trainer can run over the whole dataset just on the GPU, and then only retrieve the values at the end.